# Compiling jade to valid handlebars html in the right way

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, pug

Im using Jade for copiling to valid handlebars html, which will be used in Meteor. I need the resulting html to look like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" {{#if this.isImportant}}checked{{/if}} title="Mark as important" />
```

The only way I know it can be achieved is to insert the desired html directly into the jade file. But it doesn't seem to be the right way to do it.

I hope you can show me the right jade code for achieving this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward but very repetitive way is just to do this:

```
{{#if this.isImportant}}
input(type='checkbox', title='Mark as important', checked)
{{else}}
input(type='checkbox', title='Mark as important')
{{/if}}
```

If you had several of these on a page you could define a mixin to avoid typing all of that out. Alternatively you could use jquery to set/unset the checked property as appropriate.